Extension of a matrix Lie group isomorphism
Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and suppose $G \subseteq GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a non-trivial matrix Lie group where the group operation is the matrix multiplication. We further suppose that for any $g\in G$, $\operatorname{det}(g)\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ and that the following subgroup of $G$ is non-trivial and proper:
$$
H = \big\{ g\in G: \operatorname{det}(g)=1 \big\}
$$
My question is: if $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is viewed as a matrix Lie group equipped with the matrix multiplication and $H\cong SL(n, \mathbb{R})$, do we necessarily have $G\cong GL(n, \mathbb{R})$?
Since a group isomorphism is not necessarily linear, I wonder if we can always find an isomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H @>>> G @>{\operatorname{det}}>> \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}\\
@V{\cong}VV @V{\varphi}VV @V{=}VV \\
SL(n, \mathbb{R}) @>>> GL(n, \mathbb{R}) @>{\operatorname{det}}>> \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}
\end{CD}
$$

If elements of $G$ are invertible matrices, then you need not suppose their determinant is nonzero. And, no, $G$ need not be all of $GL(n)$.

As written, $G = \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is an easy counterexample but I assume you wanted $H$ to be a proper subgroup. Even without that you can easily find matrices with complex entries but real determinant to extend $H$ by.

@Callum Thanks for pointing it out. I do want $H$ to be proper. I suppose you mean it would not be hard to find an example that makes the diagram commute?

You also need some connectedness assumption, because otherwise we can take $G = {g\in\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})\mid \det g = \pm 1}$

No I mean it is not hard to find a group that contains $H$ as a proper subgroup but that is not contained in $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Simply take $g\in \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C}) \setminus \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ with $\det (g) \in \mathbb{R}$ and take $G$ to be the group generated by $g$ together with $H$.

@Callum Indeed. Perhaps I should instead consider a necessary condition for $G$ to be isomorphic to $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

@VladimirLysikov That is another nice counterexample. I should add more restrictions to make my question less trivial.
